# redirect to another page after login in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

In Yii when you login by default it redirects to the index page. I want that when I will login to Yii the page will redirect to another page not the index page. So can anyone help me in this. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciable.here is my actionLogin function in siteController.php

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        return $this->goBack();
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: which page  you want ???

Comment: After login I want to redirect to the admin page

Comment: `retuen $this->redirect(['contoller', 'action']);`

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect to the page you prefere

```
  public function actionLogin()
  {
      if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
          return $this->goHome();
      }

      $model = new LoginForm();
      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
         return $this->redirect(['/admin/index']);
      }
      return $this->render('login', [
          'model' => $model,
      ]);
  }
```

or if need  show an instance eg: the view for the id =  $model->id

```
      public function actionLogin()
  {
      if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
          return $this->goHome();
      }

      $model = new LoginForm();
      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
         return $this->redirect(['/admin/view',  'id' => $model->id]);
      }
      return $this->render('login', [
          'model' => $model,
      ]);
  }
```

Comment: explain better  you comment is not clear to me  ...you mean adimin/id=3..?

Comment: Anyway answer updated  with a sample for view an  istance

Answer (score 0):

Here an example
Open your views folder and open site folder and create a new page instead index.php ,just assume the new page is welcome.php and replace index by welcome in your controller like below

```
   public function actionLogin() 
{
 if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) 
{ 
return $this->goHome(); 
}
 $model = new LoginForm(); 
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login())
 {
 return $this->goBack(); 
}
 return $this->render('welcome', [ 'model' => $model, ]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the login page as this

```
 public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(['site/loader']);
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

and in you controller in your case i think site controller add

```
public function actionLoader()
{
     return $this->render('yourPage');
}
```

hope that was helpful.